# OpenCV 2.4.2 with MinGW and gcc 4.7.1

Tags: c++, opencv

I've downloaded the newest OpenCV version (2.4.2) from the website. I'm planning on using the newest g++ compiler for MinGW i.e. version 4.7.1. I've been trying the last day trying to compile the demonstration found at: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html.

Now I'm on a Windows machine and installed it via the executable, but I don't see how it would differ in this case.

my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
project( DisplayImage )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET("OpenCV_DIR" "D:/__dev/opencv/build")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Now when I compile the example I keep getting the following error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.obj
In file included from D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_index.h:49:0,
                 from D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h:42,
                 from D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:44,
                 from D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp:50,
                 from D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv\cv.h:69,
                 from C:\cv_test\DisplayImage.cpp:1:
D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h: In member function 'void cvflann::lsh::LshTable<ElementType>::add(cvflann
::Matrix<T>)':
D:/__dev/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h:196:14: error: 'use_speed_' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I know what the error means, but can't figure out my problem.

Comment: I am not sure but [this](http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/linux-like-installation-of-opencv-230.html) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And did you try to google your problem? It seems that no, and that's very pity:

1. [undeclared variable in flann/lsh_table.h with -std=gnu++0x (Bug #2179)](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2179)
2. [compile error in opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h when compiling bgslibrary](http://answers.opencv.org/question/283/compile-error-in-opencv2flannlsh_tableh-when/)

Comment: I did. I found the first link, not the second. Guess I can't read either, I read 2.4.2 in the first link, thanks anyway

Comment: So, just so you know, this is now the first result in a Google search on this topic... Congratulations on the irony.